# Understandig output of Hibernate code

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate I have written my first hibernate code and I could not understand the output the codes related to it are:

persistence class:

```
package com.andoi.hibernate;

public class Customers {
    public int cid; //Primary key
    public String cname;
    public String email;
    public long phone;


    public Customers(){
        System.out.println("Customers->dc");
    }
    public Customers(String cname,String email,long phone){
        System.out.println("Customers->three arg");
        this.cname=cname;
        this.email=email;
        this.phone=phone;
    }
    public int getCid() {
        System.out.println("getCid()");
        return cid;
    }
    public void setCid(int cid) {
        System.out.println("setCid()");
        this.cid = cid;
    }
    public String getCname() {
        System.out.println("getCname()");
        return cname;
    }
    public void setCname(String cname) {
        System.out.println("setCname()");
        this.cname = cname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        System.out.println("getEmail()");
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        System.out.println("setEmail()");
        this.email = email;
    }
    public long getPhone() {
        System.out.println("getPhone()");
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(long phone) {
        System.out.println("setPhone()");
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

hibernate mapping document:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.andoi.hibernate">
<class name="Customers" table="jlccustomers">
<id name="cid" column="cid"  type="int">
<generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="cname" column="cname" type="string"/>
<property name="email" column="email" type="string"/>
<property name="phone" column="phone" type="long"/>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

client code:

```
package com.andoi.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import org.hibernate.*;

public class SaveInTable {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Transaction tx=null;

        try{
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg=cfg.configure();
        SessionFactory sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sf.openSession();
        tx=session.beginTransaction();
}catch(HibernateException e){
            if(tx!=null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and output as:

```
Customers->dc
getCid()
Customers->dc
getCname()
getEmail()
getPhone()
setCname()
setEmail()
setPhone()
```

My question is why my persistence class object is created and getters and setters are called.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a session factory then hibernate loads the configuration file - `hibernate.cfg.xml` and parses each and every line in it.

Now you will have the mapping file details in this configuration file, so hibernate parses each and every mapping file (*.hbm.xml files) and tries to validate if the mapping information is correct or not.

So based on the mapping information in `hbm` files it checks if the Java class is present and loads an instance of the class and then verifies each and every property that is mapped in hibernate mapping file with the fields available in Java class and ensures that proper setter and getter methods are available for each and every field. That is the reason you are seeing the calls to default constructor and getter and setter methods of your Java class. Suppose if you have a field in Java class for which the mapping is not there in `hbm` file then hibernate won't look for that field and its corresponding getter & setter methods.